# Invoke Rest APIs in powershell and await for the response

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, powershell-core

I am very new to PowerShell. I am running multiple rest API calls in one powershell script using `Invoke-RestMethod` and the second rest api call returns 200, but it fails at what it needs to do. It looks like it is failing because the first API endpoint has not finished the work.

Because when I run the second api separately in the separate script, it runs fine. Is there a async and await in powershell invoke-rest method function

Current code

```
try {
    #First Rest API It works fine
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body  
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Failed"
    
}

try {
    #Second Rest API This returns 200 but does not do the work and if I run this API in a separate script
    #It runs fine in a separate script
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body  
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Failed"  
}
```

Just wanted to see if I can await the first rest method

Comment: If you're on Powershell 7, they've introduced the `ForEach-Object - Parallel` method, and you could look into runspaces, but there is no async function like JS has afaik.

Comment: @AndrewRyanDavis So how do we wait for the response. Should we always have one rest api per script?

Comment: @LearnAspNet `Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't return until it has fully read and parsed the response from the API endpoint. If the API is designed in an asynchronous manner, then you need to use whatever API endpoints are available to track the status of your previous request.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen But will it start running the next API in powershell or await for the response. Because I want the first API to await and then run the next one like we can do in C#. Is it possible with powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what Mathias stated in their comment  `Invoke-RestMethod` Will return only when it completes what it's doing with the API.

If the API you're using has a GET method that allows you get a status of the POST in question, you can do something like this.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
do
{
    # Let's assume it returns a string: "OK"
    $status = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
}
while($status -ne "OK")
```

Comment: The API does not have a get method to get the response of ok. I want to wait for the response of the first API and then call the next API to use the response of 1st API. Can I await that call.
I understand that it will only return when it completes but does it call the next line and next API before returning the response from the first API?

Comment: @LearnAspNet Typically, PowerShell will run each command in the line order it's written. Normally, PowerShell will not continue past the first  `Invoke-RestMethod`, until that command hits the endpoint, receives the response from the endpoint, and returns the response to stdout, or otherwise errors out. That second `Invoke-RestMethod` is already "waiting" for the previous `Invoke-RestMethod` by virtue of being on a later line. You can even put the POST response into a variable, and run an if statement. `if($response){do the next API call}`

Comment: Not sure if it is the API that locks the resource for few seconds but it di not work for me so I had to use Start-Sleep to make sure API is completed