# Paging through non-paged results in MS Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I used to use a Microsoft Intune GraphAPI endpoint of:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/$ApplicationID/devicestatuses
```

I used this in a PowerShell script, to get a list of devices that had a specific application/application ID installed.

This was in the Beta channel, but is no longer available. I have found I can use the following instead, as it is what the Intune portal uses to produce the same kind of on screen report:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/reports/getDeviceInstallStatusReport
```

The issue I have with this compared to the old one, is that the old one had paginated responses, and we could submit multiple calls with the paging link to return all results. The new one I am using does not present server side pagination, so I am instead having to use the "top" and "skip" body properties to iterate through all records that exist.

I am finding that using this method using the code below, is very intermittent at returning all results (sometimes it does, sometimes it only returns a random portion of the results before failing):

```
$GraphAPIResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/deviceManagement/reports/getDeviceInstallStatusReport"

$Skip = 0
do {
    $body = @{
    select = @(
        "DeviceName"
        "UserPrincipalName"
        "InstallState"
        "DeviceId"
        "ErrorCode"
        "UserName"
        "UserId"
        "ApplicationId"
        "AppInstallState"
    )
    skip = $skip
    top = "50"
    filter = "(ApplicationId eq '$ApplicationID')"
    orderBy = @(
    )
}

$body = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$GraphAPIReturn = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accesstoken)"} -Uri $GraphAPIResource -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"

Write-Host $GraphAPIReturn
$TotalRowCount = $GraphAPIReturn.TotalRowCount
$Skip += 50
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
} while (($Skip - 50) -le $TotalRowCount)
```

I put in a 500 millisecond delay, as I suspect there is some kind of throttling or rate limiting going on during my multiple disparate calls, but this did not help. I also tried upping the "top" property to 999, which I understood to be the max, although I think Intune has its own limit of 50 results.

- Is there any reason my code would cause the behaviour I am seeing with intermittent reliability, or is it more likely that Microsoft are limiting my calls to the API because I am making too many separate calls in too short of a time?
- Given this endpoint does not expose pagination, and I paging through the results in a supported/recommended way, or should I be using some other method to iterate through all pages?
- Does anyone know of a different Intune Graph API endpoint that would give me the results I need but paginated?

Comment: There is Javascript on the page when I view the data in the Intune portal, but as I am calling a GraphAPI endpoint (I have updated question to show this), I would have thought no

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview.   Microsoft graph has a frontend and a backend.  The backend is a connection to a Azure Platform (or external data) which is where your data is coming from.  The Microsoft Graph can have lots of apps running.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure I follow what you mean in relation to this question? When you refer to the "Frontend", are you talking about the Graph Explorer page?

Comment: The Front End is you connection to the Graph API.  HTTP has two modes 1) HTTP 1.0 stream mode where all data comes with one request. 2) HTTP 1.1 chunk mode where you get a next chunk message (200 Continue) instead of 100 OK for each chunk.  The backend connection to database may be using HTTP 1.1.  Invoke-RestMethod has option to handle chunk : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4#-transferencoding

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. So do I need to consider your point about Javascript still, as I feel this is out of my control? As for the HTTP method you mention, I can see when running the report in the Intune portal, I am getting a 200 OK response with a Transfer-Encoding of Chunked. Do you suggest that if I change my commands to use Chunked mode, it may be more reliable?

Comment: If you were getting a chunked result you would get 100 Continue after each chunk and 200 OK at the end.  How long before you get results.  Time outs for queries is usually by default 30 seconds.  You may need to lengthen the command timeout.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't look as though then I am getting chunked results. Results are returned pretty much instantly, i.e. no more than a couple of seconds for each page/set. I tried increasing the delay between requesting pages, which has helped, but not perfect. This is why I believe I am running up against a throttling or limit policy set by Microsoft on the Graph API

Comment: You are not request each page.  As I said there is java code executing on the server.  Try taking out the delays inside the loop and instead add a 30 second delay before the loop and see what happens.  If you get same results than issue is displaying results and not java code.  If code works than issue is java.  Try waiting for OK like the answer at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266950/invoke-rest-apis-in-powershell-and-await-for-the-response

Comment: If I take the delay out of the loop, things become more unreliable. This is probably because it is making multiple request in quick succession and I am hitting a rate limit. I don't know why I would want a one off delay before the loop starts? Do you mean instead to move it to the beginning of the loop? Not sure it would make any difference being at start rather than end of the loop. At the moment, having a 3 second delay after each query seems to be working well.

Comment: The one delay is just for testing.  Adding multiple delays in a loop does nothing.  You have a HTTP connection that stays open until the closing tag of the HTML data. It is not like you have multiple connections opening and closing.  It is one single stream of data.  If you read the stream too quickly you get an overrun of the stream.  I usually instead of using a timer search the stream until I find the data I'm looking for in a loop.  You will get a null if not found.  So loop until you do not get a null.

Comment: Well, can confirm one delay outside of the loop makes it worse than having it in the loop (I don't have multiple delays in the loop, I have one delay per loop). As there is an Invoke-RestMethod in the loop, are you sure I'm not making multiple requests? I.e one Invoke-RestMethod request per run of the loop? The returned data isn't HTML, it's JSON. I've found the Intune rate limits, which are 100 or 200 per 20 seconds. I assume each Invoke-RestMethod counts as a request, so I could be getting close to 100 within a 20 second period

Comment: HTTP specification for 1.0 is a single stream and you only get 200 OK.  If you had 1.1 in chunk mode you have multiple you get multiple connections and after each chunk you get 100 continue.  When you specify Content-Type JSON than you wait until closing JSON data.  JSON uses matching square and curly  brackets and continues until the closing bracket is found.  Adding any delay is just preventing you from overrunning the stream data in the body of the HTTP response.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't really understand how that pertains to my issue. Surely, having a delay in between making requests (I have received the closing square and curly brackets from the JSON response), means I am helping to avoid the request limit imposed by the Intune Graph API?

Comment: It is not a limit.  You are reading faster than the data is being sent and getting an underrun.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_underrun

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256309/discussion-between-eds-and-jdweng).